# How to get PlayerGUI from a Server Script?

Tags: roblox

I am working on an inventory system and and now i need to make it save, but when trying to save it prints this in the output

PlayerGui is not a valid member of Player "Players.RidhoMBLR"

```
local function save(player)
    local invTable = {}

    for i, v in pairs(player.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Inventory.InvFrame:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("TextButton") then
            table.insert(invTable, v)
        end
    end

   dataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, invTable)
end

players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(save)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are accessing the path to the PlayerGui correctly, it is probably not replicated to the server (ie, it's existence is only observable on the client in LocalScripts).

So you will likely need to use a LocalScript to pull all of the relevant information out of the UI, and communicate it up to the server using a [RemoteEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent). So move your code to a LocalScript :

```
local players = game.Players
local saveEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent -- find your RemoteEvent here

local function save(player)
    -- only tell the server about it if we are the one leaving
    if player ~= players.LocalPlayer then
        return
    end

    -- get information about the inventory
    local inventory = player.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Inventory.InvFrame:GetChildren()
    local invTable = {}
    for i, v in ipairs(intentory) do
        if v:IsA("TextButton") then
            -- grab the text out of each button
            table.insert(invTable, v.Text)
        end
    end

   -- tell the server about our inventory
   saveEvent:FireServer(invTable)
end

players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(save)
```

Then in a server Script, listen for when clients fire the event and save their data then :

```
local saveEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent -- find that same RemoteEvent

-- listen for when players report that they are leaving
saveEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, inventoryTable)
    -- save their information
    dataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, inventoryTable)
end)
```

Comment: Alright i'll try it out, opening studio

Comment: The remote event is not firing, i have double checked the remote event is in ReplicatedStorage, and the server script is in ServerScriptService, and the LocalScript is in StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts and also checked the code. Any code can run after the saveEvent:FireServer(invTable) such as print("Test")

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. Is the path to the RemoteEvent in your server Script correct? You could test if the error is in your local script by making a simple tool that fires the event as well, just to see if the script is receiving any events.

Comment: Also, double check that there aren't any errors in the Output window

Comment: Yes it is correct. (game.ReplicatedStorage.InventorySaving), and yes it is in ServerScriptService, and yes it fires when i click using a Tool. And it works, and no there are no errors related to the Inventory

Comment: One last thing to check, otherwise, I'm not sure why this event wouldn't fire. Is the path to define the RemoteEvent in the local script correct? Is it properly pointing at `game.ReplicatedStorage.InventorySaving`?

Comment: Nevermind, yesterday i did this: LocalScript fires remote event everytime a child is added from the inventory frame, then fires to a server script that clones to a server sided inventory, then it saves just like normal using GetChildren()

Comment: How do i close this question?

Comment: Only way to close it out is to either accept an answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can't access a player's PlayerGui through the server. PlayerGui is replicated locally for each client, hence in order to interact with a Player's Gui I'd recommend using [RemoteEvents](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/networking/remote-events-and-functions). By using Remote events you'd be sending a signal to the client which can then by picked up by a LocalScript. On the local script you can then fire another RemoteEvent back to the server with a list of all the items which you can then SetAsync on the server.

Comment: So a localscript that updates everytime a child is added and fires a RemoteEvent to the server?

Comment: Yeah! If you face any problems feel free to lmk.